# FitTextJS plugin does NOT resize text when only the browser window HEIGHT changes

Tags: jquery-plugins, fittextjs

I have seven divs with id 1 to 7 in my html when I resize my window **diagonally** then the fittextjs plugin resizes the text within the 7 divs thats fine.

When I resize the window **horizontally** then the font-size decreases/increases fine...

What is **not working** as expected is: When I resize the window only **vertically** then the font-size does not decrease/shrink.

How can I make it work for the last non-working case?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FitText</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    font-family: arial;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

* { /* Every element which has a border or padding value puts this value inside the div */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

._Z {
    width: 12.50%;
}

.Stack {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

    .Stack li {
        list-style: none;
        display: table-row;
    }

        .Stack li div {
            display: table-cell;
        }

.horizontal-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.horizontal-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.vertical-center {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#responseView {
    height: 100%;
}   
    </style>

    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div id="responseView" data-bind="swipeLeftRightContentViews: $root.showMapView">
        <div style="height: 100%;"> 
           <ul class="Stack _Z" data-bind="foreach: replyTimeStack.segments">

             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div id="div1" style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">1</div>
                </li>
             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div id="div2"  style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">2</div>
                </li>
             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div id="div3"  style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;" class="horizontal-center vertical-center">3</div>
                </li>
             <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div id="div4"  style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">4</div>
                </li>
                <li style="height:14.2%;background: yellow; color: black;">
                    <div id="div5"  style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">5</div>
                </li>
              <li style="height:14.2%;background: orange; color: black;">
                    <div id="div6"  style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">6</div>
                </li>
              <li style="height:14.2%;background: green; color: black;">
                    <div id="div7"  style="border-bottom:white solid 1px;"  class="horizontal-center vertical-center">7</div>
                </li>

            </ul> 

        </div>       
   </div>   

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#div1").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
        $("#div2").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
        $("#div3").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
        $("#div4").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
        $("#div5").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
        $("#div6").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
        $("#div7").fitText(1.0, { minFontSize: '7px', maxFontSize: '16px' });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work like that, you should tweak their resizer function in the script... setting up to measure the font size based on height rather than width.

```
$this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.height() / (compressor*2), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
```

that should make it work based on the height..

Cheers!